# Using word2vec vectors to train random forest

Tags: python, nlp, random-forest, word2vec

I am working on sentiment analysis and one of my feature is to generate word embeddings using word2vec.

The dimensions i am using are 350 so i am getting an array of 350 values for each word.

1. I am planning to take the average value and use 1 value as a vector
2. Storing the values as plain values for example :

Review : i am a good boy

Vectors  for i 566 6 7 7  for am 66 7 7  7u for a  77777766 for good 6666 566 6 etc

Any help would be greatly appreciated

code

```
Here is how i solved this

cleanWords=[]
for i in range(0,len(words)):
    cleanWords.append(words[i].strip())

vectorsDict={}
for i in range(0,len(cleanWords)):
    vectorsDict[cleanWords[i]]=model.wv[cleanWords[i]]

vectorized=[]
for i in range(0,len(rTxt)):
    tokens=word_tokenize(rTxt[i])
    for word in tokens:
        for key in vectorsDict:
            if word == key:
                word=vectorsDict[key]
        a = ','.join(str(v) for v in word)
    vectorized.append(a)
```

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Haven't written code till now just trying to sort the problem first because once i got how to do it the code will be done in 10 15 mins

Comment: Here is how i solved this
    
    cleanWords=[]
    for i in range(0,len(words)):
        cleanWords.append(words[i].strip())
    
    vectorsDict={}
    for i in range(0,len(cleanWords)):
        vectorsDict[cleanWords[i]]=model.wv[cleanWords[i]]
    
    vectorized=[]
    for i in range(0,len(rTxt)):
        tokens=word_tokenize(rTxt[i])
        for word in tokens:
            for key in vectorsDict:
                if word == key:
                    word=vectorsDict[key]
            a = ','.join(str(v) for v in word)
        vectorized.append(a)

Comment: Hi. Welcome to StackOverflow. What's your question? "Any help would be greatly appreciated" is not really a question!